# Using NInject, resolving IEnumerable<T> fails when injecting a a ctor arg, but not when doing Get<IEnumerable<T>>()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

When using NInject if I set up a binding for IEnumerable, it will work if I directly request an IEnumerable, but not if another bound object requires an IEnumerable.  Is this by design?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args){
        var k = new StandardKernel();
        k.Bind<IEnumerable<int>>().ToMethod(GetInts);
        k.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>(); //Has an IEnumberable<int> constructor arg
        var works = k.Get<IEnumerable<int>>(); //returns the array of ints
        var tst = k.Get<IFoo>(); //Empty integer array is passed in by ninject???
        tst.Get(); //returns an empty integer array????
        return;
    }

    public static int[] GetInts(IContext ctx){
        return new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}


public interface IFoo{
    IEnumerable<int> Get();
}


public class Foo : IFoo{
    private int[] _vals;

    public Foo(IEnumerable<int> vals){
        _vals = vals.ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> Get(){
        return _vals;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing [Multi Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection) happening.

You could override it by adding an explicit Get to your binding:

```
k.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>()
    .WithConstructorArgument( "vals", ctx=>ctx.Kernel.Get<IEnumerable<int>>());
```

(Though if you look at the source, I'm sure you'll find a way to inhibit Multi Injection.)

Comment: If you have any thoughts on ways to turn off multi-injection then sharing would be welcome.

Comment: @jpierson Sorry, if I knew, I would have said. What is your specific problem and what have you tried so far? As I say, to completely turn off isnt something I know how to do but would expect a quick look at the code to reveal. However, my suggestion of using a `Get` inside an argument spec (being based on the problem spec) should work as a quick workaround. (IOW are you saying 'well tell us if you know' or 'you told me nothing man' ?)

Comment: well tell us if you know

Comment: Sure will. It's been a while since I've used Ninject. But rest assured I'm not attempting to conceal knowledge from you here on SO as we discuss an open source framework with a clear test suite.